# Why is range not an iterator but reversed(range) is?

Tags: python, iterator, range

How come I can call next to a reversed range but can't call it on a regular range ?

```
 r1 = range(6)
 next(r1) # Error
 r2 = reversed(range(6))
 next(r2) # -> 5
```

Comment: for the same reason `next([1])` doesn't work, but `next(reversed([1]))` works. `reversed` makes the iterator, not whatever it receives.

Comment: `range` returns a `list` not a generator. use `xrange` if you want an iterator instead of a `list`

Comment: @rednaks it's 2020, Python 2 is no more. It has ceased to be. Bereft of life, it rests in peace. It's kicked the bucket and joined the choir invisible. It's an ex-Python.

Comment: @rednaks `range` does not return a list for a very long time now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle distinction here. First, `range` is a type. An instance of `range` is not an iterator, because `range.__next__` is not defined. An instance is *iterable*, though, because `range.__iter__` is defined, so you can get an iterator with, for example, `iter(range(3))`.

```
>>> type(range(1))
<class 'range'>
>>> type(iter(range(1)))
<class 'range_iterator'>
```

`range.__next__` is not defined, but `range_iterator.__next__` is.

An instance of `range` *represents* a bounded sequence of integers, without actually *being* a bounded sequences. As such, you can have multiple independent iterators over the same range.

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> i1 = iter(r)
>>> next(i1)
0
>>> next(i1)
1
>>> next(i1)
2
>>> i2 = iter(r)
>>> next(i2)
0
>>> next(i1)
3
```

---

`reversed`, however, by definition returns an iterator. If need be, it can  call `iter` on its iterable argument in order to get an iterator to reverse. It can also use its argument's `__reversed__` method to get a reverse iterator. `range.__reversed__` yields an iterator like `range.__iter__`, but going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Because, per the [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) docs:

> Return a reverse iterator.

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), however, returns an immutable sequence.

`next()` can only be used on objects with a `__next__()` method.